# Corrupt partition table - TestDisk can't find all partitions

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery, gparted, testdisk

I was resizing a partition when my PC froze and I had no alternative to shutting down manually. Unfortunately that caused my partition table to became corrupt.

My partition table was like this:

```
Windows  NTFS, Primary

**Extended**
Data NTFS
Ubuntu (ext4)
MAC OS / iaktos L2 (hfs+) 
Virtual Machines (NTFS)
Temp (NTFS)
```

The Windows partition seems intact. I can boot into Windows using the MAC OS Live CD Bootloader. Also, Ubuntu Live CD can find it. It just won't boot. When I start my computer, I get "No such partition error" and a GRUB rescue shell.

I tried to use the TestDisk utility and this is the result:
The Virtual Machines and Temp folder are found by TestDisk. They look recoverable.
It also found an NTFS partition which I can't identify. The size doesn't match my data partition (it misses approximately 500GB).
No signs of the other partitions.

My Data partition is where I have all my files. I don't have recent backups. I was preparing to install CrashPlan and a NAS to start automatic backups when this happened. :(
The strange thing is if I run fdisk -l 
in finds a partition /dev/sda5 which I am almost sure was my data partition.

I have also read about the gpart tool (not GParted). Does anyone have any experience with it?

Any advice? What about my Ubuntu and Mac OS partitions? There are no signs of them.

Edit

Here is the result of executing the fdisk -l command using Ubuntu live CD:

```
    Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
    Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
    Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
    Warning: invalid flag 0x9093 of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

    Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0xe0c5913d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          65   293620004   146809970    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       308640778  1953519615   822439419    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5   ?  3786388151  5617242435   915427142+  c5  Unknown
```

The result of sfdisk:

```
/dev/sda1 : start=       65, size=293619940, Id= 7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=308640778, size=1644878838, Id= f
/dev/sda3 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
/dev/sda4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
```

Why can fdisk find sda5 but sfdisk cant? (/dev/sda5 is my DATA Partition). As I said that's where all my important DATA is. I need to recover this partition. Do you think there is anyway to "mount" it to copy its files or whatever?

I am running gpart right now but it is taking lots of time. I could try to recover the partitions showing with TestDisk but I am afraid to make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this all using testdisk without loosing any data. I have done a deeper search, following by an MTF fix and voila. My DATA partition was still corrupted but scandisk fix it when i started windows.

Now, its time for backups. I dont want to pass for this again.